# Using Conditions to calc column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Dataframe:

```
Date          A          B          C          D
1            10         0           0          0
2             0         25          6          7
3             0         2           5          10
4             0         10          9          7
```

I'm trying to write a func that calculates a Deduction column, every time the Date=1 the Deduction column==column A.

If Date isn't equal to 1 the Deduction col = Col B + Col C- Col D

Final Output

```
Date          A          B          C          D           Deduction       Close
1            10         0           0          0            10              10
2            10         25          6          7            24              34
3            34         2           5          10           -3              31
4            31         10          9          7            12              43
```

In the below code I'm using shift(-1) to get the val of column['Close'] from the prev row.

The below code is to give an idea of how I'm trying to approach the problem, I don't know how I can reference the column within its own definition or if there's some kind of workaround to this.

Question deleted and reposted as its something I need to submit in a couple hrs, prev question was closed as it was unclear, have tried to elaborate as much as possible in this one.

```
Final['Deduction']=np.where(Final['Date'] ==1, Final['A'],  Final['B'] + Final['C']- Final['D'])

Final['Close']=np.where(Final['Date'] ==1, Final['Deduction'],Final['Close'].shift(-1)+ Final['Deduction'] )
Final
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **cumsum()**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html

```
Final['Deduction']=np.where(Final['Date'] ==1, Final['A'],  Final['B'] + Final['C']- Final['D'])

Final['Close']=Final['Deduction'].cumsum()
Final
```